# "URL Protocol" approach for exporting SharePoint 2013 list content to XML

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, rpc, asp.net-3.5

Hell Team,

Can I still use the "URL Protocol" approach for exporting SharePoint 2013 list content to XML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587743(v=office.11).aspx

https://blog.davidjwise.com/2008/01/10/accessing-sharepoint-list-data-as-xml/

Is this approach recommended.

Thanks & Regards,
Bhanu

Comment: Can you further describe what process you are trying to implement?

Comment: We are trying to export the SharePoint 2013 list content to XML for intermediate storage. So, We though this would be best option to get all the Schema and Data in one call.                                                                                                                                 string seviceUrl = sourceSiteUrl + "_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=" + listGuid + "&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE";
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(seviceUrl);
                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse()